# Integrate $ \int \frac{2\tan x+1}{\sqrt{\tan^2 x+2\tan x+2}} \, \mathrm dx $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I tried writing $\tan^2 x+2\tan x+2$ as $(\tan x+1)^2+1$ and letting $\tan\theta = \tan x+1$ yields

$$ \int \frac{2\tan\theta-1}{\tan^2\theta-2\tan\theta+2}\,\sec\theta\,\mathrm d\theta $$

Then letting $ t = \tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$ yields

$$ \int\frac{t^2+4t-1}{t^4+2t^3-2t+1}\,\mathrm dt $$

Obviously what's next is factoring out the denominator and doing partial fraction decomposition, but this seems very hard.

I wanted to know if there's an easier method.

Comment: It is actually not that hard if you use Heaviside's formula; but it is extremely difficult if you'd want to simplify it since the result includes the four zeroes of the denominator and thus they are complex numbers. Also I am quite suspicious if it actually can be evaluated in a closed form. Where did you get the problem?

Comment: Hi. I got the problem from Charlwood Integration Problems, this is problem #8, this integral started as $\int \sqrt{\tan^2x+2\tan x+2}$ but you can easily find that it's equal to $\sinh^{-1}(\tan x+1) + the above integral$. [Link to Charlwood integrals with their solutions](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/ten_hard_integrals/CharlwoodIntegrationProblems.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t=\tan x$ to rewrite the integral as
$$ I=\int \frac{2\tan x+1}{\sqrt{\tan^2 x+2\tan x+2}} dx
=\int \frac{2t+1}{(1+t^2)\sqrt{t^2+2t+2}} dt\tag1
$$
Note that
$$
\bigg( \tan^{-1} \frac{at-a^{-1}}{\sqrt{t^2+2t+2}}\bigg)’
= \frac{a^{-1} t +ab }{(t^2+b)\sqrt{t^2+2t+2}},\>\>\>\>\>
b= \frac{1+2a^2}{a^2+a^4}$$
Set $b=1$ to obtain $a^4-a^2-1=0$, which leads to $a= \sqrt{\phi}$, with $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ the golden ratio. Hence

$$
g(t) = \frac{\phi^{-1/2} t + \phi^{1/2} }{(t^2+1)\sqrt{t^2+2t+2}} =\bigg( \tan^{-1} \frac{\phi^{1/2}t-\phi^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{t^2+2t+2}}\bigg)’
$$
and similarly
$$
h(t) =\frac{\phi^{-1/2}- \phi^{1/2} t }{(t^2+1)\sqrt{t^2+2t+2}} =\bigg( \tanh^{-1} \frac{\phi^{-1/2}t+\phi^{1/2}}{\sqrt{t^2+2t+2}}\bigg)’
$$
Then, the integrand in (1) can be decomposed as
$$
\frac{2t+1}{(1+t^2)\sqrt{t^2+2t+2}} 
= \phi^{1/2} g(t) - \phi^{-1/2} h(t)
$$
resulting in
$$I= \phi^{1/2} \tan^{-1} \frac{\phi^{1/2}t- \phi^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{t^2+2t+2}}
 - \phi^{-1/2}  \tanh^{-1} \frac{\phi^{-1/2}t+ \phi^{1/2} }{\sqrt{t^2+2t+2}}+C
$$

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment.*

If you want to use partial fraction decomposition for$$I=\int\frac{t^2+4t-1}{t^4+2t^3-2t+1}\, dt$$ you could write
$$t^4+2t^3-2t+1=(t^2+a t+b)\,(t^2+c t+d)$$ without trying to make $(a,b,c,d)$ explicit (they are irrational) and this would give

$$\frac{t^2+4t-1}{t^4+2t^3-2t+1}= \frac 1 k \Bigg[\frac {\alpha+\beta\,t}{t^2+a t+b }+\frac {\gamma+\delta\,t}{t^2+c t+d }\Bigg]$$ I do not write here the expression of the different constant (this does not present much interest). Even if we face now simple integrals, the simplification would probably be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\dfrac{2\tan x+1}{\sqrt{\tan^2x+2\tan x+2}}~dx=\int\dfrac{2(\tan x+1)-1}{\sqrt{(\tan x+1)^2+1}}~dx$$

Let $u=\tan x+1$ ,

Then $x=\tan^{-1}(u-1)$

$dx=\dfrac{1}{(u-1)^2+1}~du$

$$\therefore\int\dfrac{2(\tan x+1)-1}{\sqrt{(\tan x+1)^2+1}}~dx=\int\dfrac{2u-1}{((u-1)^2+1)\sqrt{u^2+1}}~du$$

Introduce the [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution):

Let $v=u+\sqrt{u^2+1}$ ,

Then $u=\dfrac{v^2+1}{2v}$

$du=\dfrac{v^2-1}{2v^2}~dv$

$$\begin{align}\therefore\int\dfrac{2u-1}{((u-1)^2+1)\sqrt{u^2+1}}~du&=\int\dfrac{\dfrac{2(v^2+1)}{2v}-1}{\left(\left(\dfrac{v^2+1}{2v}-1\right)^2+1\right)\left(v-\dfrac{v^2+1}{2v}\right)}\dfrac{v^2-1}{2v^2}~dv\\&=\int\dfrac{\dfrac{2(v^2-v+1)}{2v}}{\dfrac{(v^2-2v+1)^2+4v^2}{4v^2}\dfrac{v^2-1}{2v}}\dfrac{v^2-1}{2v^2}~dv\\&=\int\dfrac{4(v^2-v+1)}{(v^2-2v+1)^2+4v^2}~dv\end{align}$$

Comment: How would the rest of the integral go?